# How to verify that every call of a load test generated a successful result at the end of a process chain?

Tags: artillery

I have an application that goes like this:

```
ingestion --> queue --> validation --> persistance --> database
```

I want to load test the ingestion and at the end verify that every submitted entry is stored in the database.

I have an Artillery script that posts to ingestion and recovers the same item from the database, but it does so as part of the same scenario and since the two components are implemented separately I'm actually measuring a combined performance, instead of that of each component.

I would like to load test the ingestion component keeping hold of some search key that allow me to recover all sent items from the database. I've tried this by creating a Javascript that I call at the beginning of the ingestion scenario to generate a random search key, store it in Artillery's `context` and them at the end of the scenario call another function to recover all entries from the database.

The problem I found is that Artillery runs one copy of the scenario in each virtual client, so it calls the function each time it starts the scenario and recovers only one entry at the end. And the call to the database happens in the same scenario as the post to ingestion, so I'm again mixing performance.

What I would like to do, I suppose, would be to generate the search key in a scenario, run the posts in another scenario, and then retrieve the results in a third one. How can I do that?

Also, when I retrieve the results from the database, I would like to compare the quantity with the number of posts to ingestion. I couldn't find if `expect` works with variables returned in the `context` from function calls. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible. I have been reading the documentation and any examples I can find about Artillery scripts, and I don't see that there is any way to "chain" flows together.